# Как перевести строку бит в ASCII представление Hex числа

Tags: python, строки, кодировка, hex, ascii

Всем добра.

У меня есть потребность совершить непотребное, а именно:

Есть строка `'00001111'`, в `hex` представлении - это `'\x0f'`. Так вот, мне нужно получить `ascii` строку `'0f'`. Да-да, вы не ослышались, вместо 1 байта, получить 2.  Каким образом это сделать?
Я представляю, что можно написать функцию, которая бы разбивала исходную строку на `'\x00'` и `'\x0f'`, затем приводить все это дело к `'int'`, делать проверку на `'ABCDEF'(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)` и просто конкатенировать в строку соответствующий `ascii` символ ...

Однако, меня терзают смутные сомнения... у посла медальон, у Шпака магнитофон.
Кажется, что это можно сделать как-то более `'pythonic'`

Comment: может просто сразу сделать число и перевести в шестнадцеричку с помощью hex или format 02X

Comment: @Mike Я понимаю, что проще передавать по `Serial port`. В виде 1-го hex значения, но тут именно символами надо. То-есть, при передаче `\x0f`, по факту надо передать два байта `\x00\x66`

Comment: Не очень понял всю задачу, но по приложенному в вопросе примеру вот: `hex(int('00001111', 2))[2:].zfill(2)`

Comment: хмм, по наводке Mike, нашел решение с 02x, хотя и не понял как это работает, надо будет почитать. Также решает задачу и предложенный @gil9red вариант, хотя и тут я не понимаю, что происходит. Если кто-то даст ссылку на описание методов, буду благодарен.

Comment: @gil9red Кажется понял, к символам в `hex` числе также можно получить доступ по индексу? Я думал, что строка в формате `hex`, например '\xff', этоодин символ. Следует мне вернуться к основам...

Comment: А вам нужно именно символ получить? Тогда вот: `chr(int('00001111', 2))`

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев: `len('\xff') == 1`, `len('ff') == 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
байт в виде бит как "01"-строка -> целое число -> две hex-цифры в виде строки
```

Пример:

```
>>> "%02x" % int('00001111', 2)
'0f'
```